# Powershell 2 arrays "connected" find highest number and use in second array

Tags: arrays, powershell

i have an array with version numbers:

```
$a=@(1.2,1.3,1.0)
```

and a second array with file names:

```
$b=@(file1,file2,file3)
```

so how do i find the highest number in $a and use its indexnumber for $b?

In this example it should be something like this:

```
$dummy=$a |measure -Maximum
$i_from_a=$a[$dummy] | get-indexnumber? missing code to solve this

$fileIneed=$b[$i_from_a]
```

how do I code that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$a=@(1.2,1.3,1.0)
$aMax = $($a | sort -Descending)[0]

$file = $b[$a.indexOf($aMax)]
```

Comment: doesnt work. [System.Object[]] has no method called "indexof"

Comment: Strange.... What version of PowerShell are you using? What is the output from `$a.GetType()`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: (found $HighestValue in a very complex way...have to change that in future)

```
$i_from_a = [array]::IndexOf($a,$a[$HighestValue])
$fileIneed=$b[$i_from_a]
```

hope this works for you, i changed all the names from my script again so it should match to the question, maybe u will have to fix it a bit.

Comment: I don't understand. You use `$a[$HighestValue]` to find the index. For that to work `$HighestValue` has to already be the index. You're making a redundant call. You could combine both answers here to `$i_from_a = [array]::IndexOf($a,($a | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum); $fileIneed = $b[$i_from_a]`